# The encrypted store is not available | AWSSDK C

Tags: c#, .net, amazon-web-services, .net-5, aws-sdk-net

I'm getting the following exception using AWSSDK v 3.5.1.58:

`The encrypted store is not available.  This may be due to use of a non-Windows operating system or Windows Nano Server, or the current user account may not have its profile loaded.`

This is due to the application unable to use crypt32.dll. Now this is strange since the file is in System32 running on Server 2019 and IIS 10. There's no real documentation around this. I'm using ADFS auth. `FederatedAWSCredentials`

This works fine on local dev, but not once deployed.

The file generating the error can be found here: https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-net/blob/133eddb00a3fbd2ab395e01c3d84ac9fe1ff38b2/sdk/src/Core/Amazon.Util/Internal/SettingsManager.cs on line 213

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the issue was in IIS.

I was running the Application Pool as the user that needs to be authenticated, which is correct. But you also need to set the following:

`Application Pool -> Advanced Settings -> Process Model -> Load User Profile = True`

Answer (score 1):

[image]

1. RDP to your server
2. and follow the steps in the image